# How to add tab charcter in each line?

Tags: python

I have a file like this

```
237501.jpg#0 Two 
237501.jpg#1 Teddy
237501.jpg#2 Large 
237501.jpg#3 A teddy 
237501.jpg#4 an image 
237501.jpg#0 Two 
237501.jpg#1 Teddy
237501.jpg#2 Large 
237501.jpg#3 A teddy 
237501.jpg#4 an image
```

and i need to add tab character after each number for each line to be like this

```
237501.jpg#0     Two 
237501.jpg#1     Teddy
237501.jpg#2     Large 
237501.jpg#3     A teddy 
237501.jpg#4     an image
```

my code is

```
import os

inputFile = open("output1.txt", "r") 
exportFile = open("output10.txt", "w")
for line in inputFile:
   new_line = line.replace("#0", '#0    ')
   exportFile.write(new_line)
```

but couldn't catch the number at each line
the result i got is

```
237501.jpg#0     Two 
237501.jpg#1 Teddy
237501.jpg#2 Large 
237501.jpg#3 A teddy 
237501.jpg#4 an image
```

Comment: You're new here. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first before posting questions so we can actually help you

Comment: Seeing that the tab is inserted at the first space, perhaps `replace()` with a count parameter?

Comment: @quqa123 i edit the post with my tries

Comment: @j1-lee i alresdy used replace but i catched only one number couldn't do it for all numbers that exists at the end of each line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `enumerate`

`input.txt`:

```
237501.jpg#0 Two 
237501.jpg#1 Teddy
237501.jpg#2 Large 
237501.jpg#3 A teddy 
237501.jpg#4 an image 
237501.jpg#0 Two 
237501.jpg#1 Teddy
237501.jpg#2 Large 
237501.jpg#3 A teddy 
237501.jpg#4 an image
```

code:

```
inputFile = open("input.txt", "r")
exportFile = open("output.txt", "w")
patterns = ["#"+str(idx) for idx in range(5)]
for line in inputFile:
    for pattern in patterns:
        if pattern in line:    
            new_line = line.replace(pattern, pattern+' '*3)
            exportFile.write(new_line)
            break
inputFile.close()
exportFile.close()
```

`output.txt` result:

```
237501.jpg#0    Two 
237501.jpg#1    Teddy
237501.jpg#2    Large 
237501.jpg#3    A teddy 
237501.jpg#4    an image 
237501.jpg#0    Two 
237501.jpg#1    Teddy
237501.jpg#2    Large 
237501.jpg#3    A teddy 
237501.jpg#4    an image
```

Comment: thanks a lot it did it finally but for the first 5 lines .. the remaining lines still

Comment: @prog please provide your whole file

Comment: i post the example as  the file is too large .. all the lines in the file like that example

Comment: @prog then please provide your file pattern, such as provide 10 lines, i edit the `input.txt`.Is this file pattern suits yours?

Comment: i post the example of my file but your code did the first 5 lines ,, I'm wondering why as all the lines like the first 5 lines

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex`, iterate through each line, find substring with `#1, #2,..` for each line and replace it with the `substring + '\t'`

```py
import re
op = ''
pattern = re.compile('#\d+')
for line in file:
    num = pattern.findall(line)[0]
    op += line.replace(num, num+ '\t')

print(op)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
237501.jpg#0     Two 
237501.jpg#1     Teddy
237501.jpg#2     Large 
237501.jpg#3     A teddy 
237501.jpg#4     an image
```

Comment: thanks a lot i tried it now and got IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You hadn't really specified what kinds of data could be in the first column, but it appears that only the first space is significant. I would partition each space and just print out the pieces, skipping the middle piece.

```
with open('input.txt') as fd:
    for line in fd:
         parts = line.partition(' ')
         print('\t'.join(parts[0:3:2]), end='')
```

Comment: thanks for replying the data is a line contains the name of the image with its sentence .. i tried your code but got SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Looks like I forgot a parenthesis. I’ll correct it now.